# Параллельные вычисления

Tags: распараллеливание

Всем здравствуйте, хочу разобраться с новыми технологиями параллельных вычислений, например
GPGPU, или на CPU, это уже не столь важно и не могу подобрать практическую задачу для бакалавра для этой темы, может кто-то что-то подскажет?

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, зайдите на [projecteuler.net](http://projecteuler.net/). Там есть много задач, которые можно решить либо зная правильную методику, либо хардкорным перебором. Так вот хардкорные переборы могут работать по нескольку часов. Некоторые из приведенных задач вполне интересны. Например, [75 задачу](http://projecteuler.net/problem=75) можно решать перебором - там есть где распараллелить.